# Single node Hbase Connection issues

Tags: java, hbase, hadoop2

Hi I am trying to setup a single node Hbase on my home Lan, and trying to connect from home computer to the server.
However the connection times out with no data sent. The port is open and I can ssh to the server all ok. Now following the ideas set out in this link
[Not able to connect to remote Hbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176254/not-able-to-connect-to-remote-hbase)

I modified the hbase-site.xml,regionservers and /etc/hosts to:
 `#127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.0.115 hbase localhost`

Site-xml

```css
<property>
 <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
  <value>192.168.0.115</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.master.info.bindAddress</name>
<value>192.168.0.115</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.master.info.port</name>
  <value>60010</value>
</property>
```

regionservers:

```
localhost
192.168.0.115
```

The info site still has Master at localhost so I guess there is still a configuration issue ?

Thanks

Comment: can you give the log of the error when you try to connect?

Comment: @Whitefret Which logfile do you need ?